# Very high fan speeds after system goes into suspend 14.04

Tags: suspend, fan

When system begins sleep, there is a very high fan speed that can be heard throughout the room.  I thought it was someone using a hairdryer at first.

How do I resolve this, and if I can't resolve this, how dangerous is a very high fan speed for maybe 1.5 seconds?

Specs

- 14.04
- r9 390
- i3 6100
- Cooler Master fans

This problem is unique from other problems on here in that the fans begin spinning fast when suspend begins, rather than when the computer is awoken.

This problem is not replicated using Windows 10.

Comment: Have you put the BIOS in Legacy mode?

Comment: I'll try that.  Unfortunately my system now only boots into a lui right after I updated it.   So that is another problem I'll have to fix.  I don't know how many times Linux is going to have to fail me before I give up

Comment: You dont need to run the OS to get into the BIOS. If secure boot is enabled the BIOS wont load the linux graphics driver. Could also be the source of your fan issue.